# Postgres load balance with limited hardware resources

Tags: postgresql, performance, load-balancing

I've got a task to do and some limited hardware resources, as always.

I need to setup postgres server with single database, with a table of largeobjects (3TB+) and a few small, heavily accessed tables (<10 GB).

I've got old physical server with ~5 TB of harddisk space, with limited CPU and RAM, I can also use much faster (in CPU and RAM) virtual server - but limited in storage.

I won't have much DELETE statements, most SELECT statements will be to recent data. There will be one simultanous connection doing all the job, client on one host only.

I see a few scenarios:

1. Postgres on virtual machine with remote storage (single instance)
2. Postgres on old hardware with local storage (single instance)
3. Postgres on both, with some kind of replication (high speed virtual machine for new data, low speed for older data on the old hardware)
4. Any other ideas?

Is it even possible to replicate just the most recent part of the postgres database?

90% of SELECT queries will be to the most recent ~5-10 gigabytes of data, but I need seamless access to the rest 2,990 TB.

What should I do? (except buying appropriate hardware;)

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't really matter as long as you have enough RAM to buffer the 10GB of heavily accessed data.

You'll need some additional RAM to read large objects without pushing the 10GB out of the cache, but that shouldn't be a problem on today's machines.

If all your work is done on one connection, that sounds like there will be no high load on the database.

So I wouldn't really worry about scaling with requirements like that.

Your biggest worry should probably be how to backup 3TB of data in a reasonable time.

**Edit:** If you have much less memory, you should take the machine with the faster storage.

Comment: In fact, I will have about 2 GB of RAM, it is not "today's machine" : (

Backups will probably be performed incrementally, so a full backup won't be needed often. 

I'll try and let You know ; )

Comment: I have added advice for machines with little RAM.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I've checked several different scenarios and decided not to keep files/largeobjects in database.

Postgres with database location mounted over NFS (v4) had some lags - It was faster but it was choking for a few seconds periodically, i decided to store plain files over NFS which is significantly slower but more stable.

I'm sure there was a way to tune it, but this solution is fine too.

Postgres is used for file index and keeps their files on local harddisk.